# Is Zoetrope an independent demon?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-2, the-conjuring-universe

The Conjuring 2 is one of the best horror movies I have watched, but there is one thing that I am confused about.

The boy has a Zoetrope toy, the Crooked man; and the Crooked man actually comes to life and terrifies the little boy.

I am under the impression that this Crooked man is a demon that is not associated with the Nun-demon, e.g. this Crooked man will hunt the family even if the Nun-demon had not been there.

My reasons are:

1. Unlike the old man ghost, there is no indication that the Nun-demon has forced this Crooked man into its service.
2. After the Nun-demon is vanquished, Warrens still take the Zoetrope into their museum in order to keep the Crooked man under watch, like the first movie, where Annabelle doll is an independent demon spirit.

But one can easily ask one question, why this Zoetrope demon terrorizes this particular family? It might have been ordered by the nun-demon.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: one of the best? Seriously ;)

Comment: @AJ Not 2 but part 1 was definitely one of the bests. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no evidence in the movie that **Zoetrope** used to terrorize the little boy on the order of that Nun demon. It just had two or three appearances in the entire movie.

Therefore, it is safe to assume that Zoetrope was an independent demon. It was just another artifact possessed by a demon just like that Annabelle doll.

> Why this Zoetrope demon terrorize this particular family?

You can't expect good behavior from demon, can you? Of course not, as movies/TV shows suggested. Demons are used to haunt the house and its residents where they live. And that is what Zoetrope demon was doing.

Lastly, who knows producers might make a movie about Zoetrope just like Annabelle. ;)

Comment: They are making a movie about Zoetrope indeed. :-D And a movie about the Nun.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the other answer. I am looking forward to watch this.

Answer (score 3):

As AJ speculated, they are planning a film about *The Crooked Man*:

> On May 31, 2017, Safran said there was a possibility of a Crooked Man film. On June 14, 2017, it was reported that a spin-off film titled The Crooked Man, featuring the character of the same name from The Conjuring 2, was in development with Mike Van Waes writing the script based on a story treatment by James Wan. Wan and Safran are set to produce the project. In August 2017, Wan told Entertainment Weekly that The Crooked Man is still at the beginning of the development process, stating that the film is in "early stages" and that the intent with the potential film is to move into the "dark fairytale" subgenre of horror films. - [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conjuring_(film_series)#The_Crooked_Man)

So hopefully we might get answer about the motivations of The Crooked Man.

Even [The Nun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nun_(2018_film)) is coming which is again a spinoff of *The Conjuring 2*.

Comment: True, Very looking forward to this movie.